# Deploying Postfix, how to setup DNS to point to server?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I've set up a postfix server, listening on port 25 on an Azure VM (Ubuntu). I've just used the default configuration but set the domain to my domain

> example.com

In the DNS management, what does the MX record need to look like? is it simply just the IP of the server?

```
# example.com

mail         aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

I've followed a few tutorials, but none seem to cover all aspects of deployment, like when some cloud providers block port 25, how do I set up a relay?

Is there a good tutorial of setting up a mail server with a domain from start to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how MX record in DNS should look like:

```
Domain          TTL   Class    Type  Priority      Host
example.com.        1936    IN  MX  10         onemail.example.com
example.com.        1936    IN  MX  10         twomail.example.com
```

(source [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record))

You can check also [this article](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/e-mail/technical-matters/mx-record/) for explanations

```
<name>: The first field contains the domain name.  
<ttl>: Time to live specifies how long the information is guaranteed to be valid. 
<class>: The class field specifies the type of network.  
<type>: The DNS record type in this case is MX.  
<priority>: The smaller the value, the higher the mail server’s priority.  
<rdata>: Resource data defines the mail server name.
```